# How to extract .tar.bz2 in node.js using streams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, tar, bzip2

I'm trying to extract some .tar.bz2 files in node.js. I'm searching here, in npm, github and teh google for this but there is no ready solution.

My files are ~25mb each so I think the best way would be in a piped stream with the `tar` module (similar to how you use the Gunzip from node.js's built-in ZLib library for .tar.gz). This way I can also extract directly from piped http using `request`.

I found https://github.com/Woodya/node-gzbz2 (and it's many renamed forks like `gzbz`) but they require external dependencies build using `node-gyp`. I don't want to use these since the module I'm building has to work without hassle on linux, mac and windows using just npm and without depending on external libraries like python.

Alternately I look at https://github.com/cscott/seek-bzip (and it's sources) and I like how it is pure javascript but it only decodes Buffers.

Can anybody advice me on the way to go here?

edit: The author of `seek-bzip` kindly created a wrapper to turn his synchronous streams into asynchronous ones, but this fix depends on `node-fibers` which again uses `node-gyp` which in my case is undesirable. See https://github.com/cscott/seek-bzip/issues/1

edit2: I'm still looking for a cross-platform solution, but here is a quick way to do this using CLI commands:

```
var cmd = 'bunzip2 -c ' + sourceFile + ' | (cd ' + targetDir + '; tar -xf -)';

require('child_process').exec(cmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
        // bad
    }
    // yea!
});
```

Comment: but have you tried using node-gzbz2? was there any compilation error?, node-gyp is precisely intended to make c/c++ libs work on every platform where node works.

Comment: While that is technically true, but like I state in the OP: in practice node-gyp does not work for many Windows users because it requires Visual Studio and other stuff like python many regular users don't have installed. In my case that was a show-stopper.

Comment: fair enough, native libs compilation on windows is still a mess. I think the best solution so far is to provide precompiled assemblies for windows, but most lib mantainers don't do that.

Comment: Indeed, although there is https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-pre-gyp but  many node devs don't care for windows.

Comment: I personally always use @shockpkg/archive-files for that

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this question is really 2 questions: how to decrypt bz2 and how to untar. I'll answer the untaring part. The [tar-stream](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-stream) module is a pretty good one:

```
var tar = require('tar-stream')    

var extract = tar.extract();
extract.on('entry', function(header, stream, callback) {
    // make directories or files depending on the header here...
    // call callback() when you're done with this entry
});

fs.createReadStream("something.tar").pipe(extract)

extract.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('done!')
});
```